# Very Basic Question: Calculation of Moment of Inertia Tensor

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I am studying from the book Classical Dynamics: A Contemporary Approach by Jose & Saletan, and at page 496, they work through an example about the moment of inertia tensor of a uniform cube
(sorry about the writing on the picture, I don't have an eraser with me right now),

[image]

[image]

where they have calculated the moment of inertia tensor with respect to the fixed point in space. What I don't understand is the reason why we calculate it with respect to a *point*, when the physical meaning of the moment of inertia is the opposition to the angular acceleration due to the distribution of mass with respect to the *axis* of rotation. What is the motive behind calculating it with respect to a point?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_tensor): “For the same object, different axes of rotation will have different moments of inertia about those axes. … The moment of inertia tensor is a convenient way to summarize all moments of inertia of an object with one quantity. … $I_n=n \cdot I \cdot n$”

Answer (score 0):

with

$$ \vec L = {\bf I} \vec\omega $$

the direction of $\vec\omega$ is not specified. It just needs to be relative to the point.